# Is the second argument in connect() indefinite or limited to 0-5

Tags: web-audio-api

If you want to use channel splitters and/or channel mergers you need to use the second and third arguments in the `connect(node,0,0)` method.

I want to know if these numbers are limited to 5 channels or if these arguments are indefinite numbers.

```
splitter.connect(node,0) // is this number limited to 0-5 ?
```

It seems like the spec should be indefinite to handle odd multi channel file types but it seems that it is relegated to 6 channels and less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A splitter node can have as many channels as you want (up to some limit).  You have to specify how many when you create the splitter.  The default is 6.  See http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-BaseAudioContext-createChannelSplitter-ChannelSplitterNode-unsigned-long-numberOfOutputs